# Shopify product grid - don't align the rows in 1 line

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

I have a regular Shopify collection product grid that looks like this:

[Current Product Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNFPH.png)

I'd like to make it look more this feed (e.g. Pinterest-style grid, eliminating the white space under product 1, 2, 4 and 5):

[Desired Product Grid Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRwO9.jpg)

Below my grid css right now:

```
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  column-gap: var(--grid-mobile-horizontal-spacing);
  row-gap: var(--grid-mobile-vertical-spacing);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  .grid {
    column-gap: var(--grid-desktop-horizontal-spacing);
    row-gap: var(--grid-desktop-vertical-spacing);
  }
}

.grid:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.grid__item {
  width: calc(25% - var(--grid-mobile-horizontal-spacing) * 3 / 4);
  max-width: calc(50% - var(--grid-mobile-horizontal-spacing) / 2);
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Masonry effect on collection page instead of updating it using CSS only.

https://masonry.desandro.com/ is good Masonry library.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).